# Datatable is not getting refreshed in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

I have a bunch of data from my server call so i decided to use datatable using angularjs. While implementing the i am getting 10 records at every pagination call.
But the problem is while clicking on the next paging it brings the data and refelects the datatable but while clicking on the previous paging it brings the data but not refelected to datatable.
Here is my chunk of angularjs code:-

```
appice.controller('appUsersController',
    function ($scope,appIceService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $q) {

    function init(){
        $scope.getAppUsers();
    }

    //$scope.dtInstance = {};
    $scope.type = '';
    $scope.getAppUsers = function(type){
        $scope.type = type;
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withFnServerData(serverData)
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('searchDelay', 350)
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10);

        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('alias').withTitle('User'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fs').withTitle('User Since'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('sc').withTitle('#of Sessions'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ad').withTitle('Average Duration'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ca').withTitle('Competing Apps'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('interest').withTitle('Interests'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('engage').withTitle('Campaign Engagement'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('cac').withTitle('CAC'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('ltv').withTitle('LTV'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('permission').withTitle('Permission')
        ];
    }

    $scope.getUsers = function(userType){
        $scope.getAppUsers(userType);
    }

    function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
        //All the parameters you need is in the aoData variable
       /* var draw = aoData[0].value;
        var order = aoData[2].value;*/
        var start = aoData[3].value;
        //console.log('draw::'+draw+" order:"+order+" start:"+start);
        var length = aoData[4].value;
        var searchText = aoData[5].value.value;
        var promise = appIceService.getAppUsers($scope.type, start, length, searchText);
        promise.then(function(result) {
            if(result){
                var records = {
                        'draw': result.draw,
                        'recordsTotal': result.recordsTotal,
                        'recordsFiltered': result.recordsFiltered,
                        'data': result.data  
                    };
                //$scope.rerender();
                //$scope.dtInstance.rerender(); 
                fnCallback(records);
                $scope.$apply();
                //console.log('records:'+JSON.stringify(records));
            }
            else{
                console.log('else records::')
                fnCallback({});
            }            
        });
    }

    init();
});
```

And this is my html code.

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong in this while implementing the datatable using angularjs .

Comment: What component/ service you use for table rendering?

Comment: nodejs environment and mongodb

Comment: ok... I've seen tag 'datatables'. So, usually problem is that jQuery works outside of AngularJS [$digest cycle](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle).
I think you need bind your AngularJS update-function to jQuery event-handler.